# Magento 2 .1: second store view with symlinks: "Requested store not found"

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, stores

I have created a second store view with **symlinks** in my store in Magento 2.1.

Theme is coming in admin but not showing in frontend. In admin when I save data it getting **"requested store is not found error"**.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your refreshed Magento's cache?

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Comment: Tried these but still no luck

Comment: Yes. not worked for me. facing the same issue. If got any solution @nadh